# html input button server click event not fire

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have the following code inside the CS file of the page, i am trying to add an html button inside a div in the server side to close the alert modal dialog.
When I add the event to the button and try to fire it. The event doesn't fires.
So, where is the problem ?

```html
public Alert(HtmlGenericControl alert ,string alertMessage)
        {
            vAlert = alert;

            alert.Attributes.Add("class", "uk-modal");
            alert.Attributes.Add("aria-hidden", "true");
            alert.Attributes.Add("style", "display: none; overflow-y: scroll;");

            HtmlGenericControl innerDiv = new HtmlGenericControl();
            innerDiv.TagName = "div";
            innerDiv.Attributes.Add("class", "uk-modal-dialog");
            innerDiv.Attributes.Add("style", "top: 35.5px;text-align:center; padding:30px;");

            HtmlInputButton btnclose = new HtmlInputButton();
            btnclose.Attributes.Add("type", "button");
            btnclose.Attributes.Add("id", "alert_close");
            btnclose.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
            btnclose.Attributes.Add("class", "uk-modal-close uk-close");
            btnclose.Attributes.Add("style", "padding:15px;");
            
            btnclose.ServerClick += new EventHandler(btnclose_ServerClick);
            innerDiv.Controls.Add(btnclose);
            

            HtmlGenericControl p = new HtmlGenericControl();
            p.TagName = "p";
            p.InnerText = alertMessage;
            innerDiv.Controls.Add(p);

            alert.Controls.Add(innerDiv);

            ShowAlert(alert);
        }

        private void btnclose_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HideAlert(vAlert);
        }
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: add the part with Button's part from shtml/aspx file

Comment: how can you give me an example ?

Comment: ¿In wich event are you adding the controls? Page life cycle I mean.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. But i am trying to show/hid a dialog in the button click event in the server side without using either a javascript or a jquery

Comment: @YusufShayah At what event are you creating controls. You should suppose to do it `Page_Init`

Answer (score 2):

The button probably doesn't exist at the time when the server callback is executing.

You are using a dynamically created button. In order for it to be able to trigger a server side method, the button needs to be added and have it's event handler bound in an early stage of the page life cycle, such as On_Init.

We don't know when you call your "Alert" method, but it might very well  too late. It also needs to be called on every postback - or the link between button and handler won't be there when the button causes a postback.